# Displaying services running that are in the context of SYSTEM privileges using the Windows command line

Tags: windows, permissions, services

I have been trying to figure out how to put together a proper way of doing this but using `findstr` to try and match the output of the services running does not seem to be properly doing it.

I have tried using

`sc queryex type= service`

and piping that through in order to filter for only those with system privileges, but I'm not sure I'm doing it right. I thought about piping the output to `accesschk.exe` utility and trying to match only those with permissions that I can modify but still not getting anywhere. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use this powershell command and output to a file.  ...... Get-Service | Where Status -eq "Running" | Out-GridView

Answer (score 0):

You need to use PowerShell for getting this information.

For listing services with their names, account and starting-mode use:

```
Get-WmiObject win32_service | Format-Table name, startname, startmode
```

You may further select the ones you require by filtering the list
with a chained
[Where-Object command](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-7.2).

For more information see
[The Scripting Wife Uses PowerShell to Find Service Accounts](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/the-scripting-wife-uses-powershell-to-find-service-accounts/).

Comment: I personally prefer using the WQL syntax to the Powershell syntax as it works everywhere (including powershell).  Sometimes, I use the `wbemtest` tool and build my queries there.  Although deprecated, he can use `WMIC` from cmd.exe too.  It will be around for a long time even if it isn't being maintained.  WMI is not going to change any time soon.  Powershell is certainly the way to go if starting from scratch but if OP is already in batch with a complicated system.. OP needs to pick options carefully.